# How can I play a Blu-Ray movie on Google TV without first ripping it to another format?

Tags: video-streaming, media-player, blu-ray

If I put a Blu-Ray disc into the Blu-Ray drive on my PC, is there an easy way to cast\stream it to my Goolge TV dongle that does not involve ripping the movie first (Just playing it live straight from the disc to the dongle rather than to my PC monitor)?

So that I wouldn't need to spend ages ripping a movie that I'm probably only going to watch once or twice ever, or which I'm borrowing from a friend and don't want to rip at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may cast the Blu-Ray to the ChromeCast using the free
[VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/):

- Run VLC
- Run menu *Playback > Renderer > Scan*
  (if the ChromeCast is not already listed),
  and click the ChromeCast
- Start playing the video in VLC
  using the menu "Media > Open File" or just drag and drop a video file
  onto the VLC window.
  If you see an “Insecure site” prompt, click “View certificate”
  and then “Accept Permanently” to accept the Chromecast’s certificate.
- The video should now play on the Chromecast.

If the WiFi network is too slow, the Blu-Ray might not play well.

For more details see the article
[How to Stream From VLC to Your Chromecast](https://www.howtogeek.com/269272/how-to-stream-from-vlc-to-your-chromecast/).